# Can't see Invocable Variable within visual workflow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

Part of a visual workflow I am creating invokes a method which should contain an invocable variable (newPattern) to parse info back.  Unfortunately when I go into the flow to find the output it says "This element has no outputs".

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class AutoNumberPatternChecker {

public static String getNextChar(String oldChar){
    String nextChar = '';
    if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('A')){
        nextChar = 'B';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('B')){
        nextChar = 'C';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('C')){
        nextChar = 'D';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('D')){
        nextChar = 'E';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('E')){
        nextChar = 'F';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('F')){
        nextChar = 'G';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('G')){
        nextChar = 'H';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('H')){
        nextChar = 'I';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('I')){
        nextChar = 'J';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('J')){
        nextChar = 'K';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('K')){
        nextChar = 'L';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('L')){
        nextChar = 'M';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('M')){
        nextChar = 'N';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('N')){
        nextChar = 'O';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('O')){
        nextChar = 'P';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('P')){
        nextChar = 'Q';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('Q')){
        nextChar = 'R';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('R')){
        nextChar = 'S';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('S')){
        nextChar = 'T';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('T')){
        nextChar = 'U';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('U')){
        nextChar = 'V';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('V')){
        nextChar = 'W';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('W')){
        nextChar = 'X';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('X')){
        nextChar = 'Y';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('Y')){
        nextChar = 'Z';
    }else if(oldChar.equalsIgnoreCase('Z')){
        nextChar = 'A';
    }

    return nextChar;
}   

    public class newPattern{
    @InvocableVariable(label='newPattern' required='true')
    public String newPattern;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Create New Pattern' description='Looks at the current pattern and determines the next appropriate pattern')
public static void updateNewPattern(){

    AutoNumber_Tracker__c autoNum;
    autoNum = [SELECT Pattern__c, Counter__c FROM AutoNumber_Tracker__c WHERE Object_Name__c = 'Project' ORDER BY Counter__c DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1];

    String strPattern = autoNum.Pattern__c;

    String newPattern = '';

            if(strPattern.length() == strPattern.countMatches('Z') ){

                for(Integer i = 0; i <= strPattern.length(); i++){
                    newPattern += 'A';
                }

            }else{

            Map<Integer, String> mapKey = new Map<Integer, String>();
            Map<Integer, String> newMapKey = new Map<Integer, String>();

            for(Integer i = 0; i < strPattern.length(); i++){
                mapKey.put(i+1, strPattern.substring(i,i+1));
            }               
            System.debug('*********String mapKey : '+mapKey);

            Boolean stillUpdate = true;

            for(Integer i = strPattern.length() ; i > 0; i--){
                if(stillUpdate){
                        if(mapKey.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase('Z')){
                            newMapKey.put(i,getNextChar(mapKey.get(i)));
                        }else{
                            stillUpdate = false;  //otherwise change stillUpdate to false and run the getNextChar method to figure out what other letter should be there and put that into the newMapKey
                            newMapKey.put(i,getNextChar(mapKey.get(i)));
                        }
                    }else{ 
                        newMapKey.put(i,mapKey.get(i));
                    }   
                }
                System.debug('*********String newMapKey : '+newMapKey);

                newPattern = '';     

                for(Integer i = 0; i < strPattern.length(); i++){
                    newPattern += newMapKey.get(i+1);
                }    
                System.debug('*********String newPattern : '+newPattern);    
            }
        strPattern = newPattern; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm still researching this, but your first method could be written as follows: `public static String getNextChar(String oldChar) {
    String key = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA';
    Integer index = key.indexOf(oldChar.toUpperCase());
    return key.substring(index+1, index+2);
}`

Comment: That's awesome!  I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it says it has no output is because you do not return anything from your @innvocable method .

Your @innvocable method is void and hence the issue .

```
@Innvocable
public static String updateNewPattern(){
 return newPattern
}
```

You can create a String Innvocable variable instead of the custom class for your scenario

Comment: I had a bit of trouble with converting the method from void to string so spoke to Salesforce.  The invocable method needs a list input as well as the return: public static List<ANPatternChecker> updateNewPattern(List<ANPatternChecker> AndObj){